# How to write a loop for such sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write such query:

```
SELECT CAST (date_time_column AS DATE)  as 'Date',
 AVG(CASE WHEN FORMAT(date_time_column, 'HH:mm') = '00:00' then my_values ELSE NULL end) as '00:00',
 ........
 AVG(CASE WHEN FORMAT(date_time_column, 'HH:mm') = '23:59' then my_values ELSE NULL end) as '23:59'
 FROM table
 where date_time_column > '2021-08-12'
 GROUP BY CAST (date_time_column AS DATE)
```

What is a way to avoid writing 1440 lines in a query?

Comment: By using a normalised approach. *Why* do you want a column for every different minute of the day? Smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I need per minute dynamics of the indicator per day

Comment: That doesn't explain why you don't want to use a normalised approach.

Comment: This, in fact, is my question. What approach should be taken for this task?

Comment: If you want a **row** for every minute, then use a tally to create a row for each minute of the day.

Comment: I want a column for every minute

Comment: So I go back to my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758092/how-to-write-a-loop-for-such-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment121515180_68758092): *"Why do you want a column for every different minute of the day?"* Though the sort answer is if you want a column for every minute, then yes, ***you*** need to define those columns.

Comment: The [maximum number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) of columns per table is 1,024.  Not enough it seems

Comment: You can have more than that in a result set, @SteveC .

Comment: *Result set* @SteveC , not Table. If you did `SELECT * FROM [TableWith1024Columns] CROSS JOIN [TableWith1024Columns];` you'd have a *result set* with 2048 columns.

Comment: In other words, there is basically no other way. Understood thanks. I’ll think if I can really output the data into rows, not into columns, and then I’ll think about how to process them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below method (Change the variables  to match your table and field)

```
/*Generate all minutes in a day in a string variable*/
Declare @timeRange varchar(max)=null
declare @startdate Datetime='2021-08-12 00:00';
; WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 1 i, @startdate AS resultDate
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1, DATEADD(minute, i, @startdate )
FROM cte 
WHERE DATEADD(minute, i, @startdate ) < DateAdd(day,1,@startdate)
)

SELECT @timeRange=Coalesce(@timeRange +',' +  '['+Format(resultDate,'HH:mm')+']','['+Format(resultDate,'HH:mm')+']') FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000);




/* (Change These variables to match your table & fields  */
declare @filterQuery varchar(300)=' where {date_time_column}>''2021-01-01''';
declare @dateTimeColumn varchar(30)='{date_time_column}';
declare @valueColumn varchar(30)='{value_column}';
declare @myTable  varchar(20)='{my_table}';


/*Generate Pivot Query */
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

set @query= '
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Cast('+ @dateTimeColumn +' as Date) Resultdate, 
       FORMAT(' + @dateTimeColumn + ', ''HH:mm'') DateMinute, 
       ' + @valueColumn + ' FROM ' + @myTable + ' ' + @filterQuery +'
     ) FormattedData
PIVOT( AVG('+ @valueColumn + ')   
    FOR DateMinute IN ('+ @timeRange +')
     ) AS pivotTable

';

/*Execute Generated Query*/

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to return your data in *rows*, not columns.  That is a row for every minute rather than a column for every minute.

Try it something like this:

```
WITH 
cteNums AS
(
    Select  TOP (1440) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (Select Null)) - 1 as num
    From    sys.all_columns
    Order By num
)
, cteMinutes AS 
(
    Select  FORMAT(CAST(num/cast(1440.0 as real) as DATETIME), N'HH:mm') as Minutes
    From cteNums
)
select  CAST(t.date_time_column AS DATE)  as 'Date',
        m.Minutes,
        AVG(CASE WHEN FORMAT(t.date_time_column, 'HH:mm') = m.Minute then t.my_values ELSE NULL end) as AvgValues
FROM cteMinutes m
LEFT JOIN [table] t   ON m.Minutes = FORMAT(t.date_time_column, 'HH:mm')
where t.date_time_column > '2021-08-12'
GROUP BY CAST(t.date_time_column AS DATE), m.Minutes
ORDER BY CAST(t.date_time_column AS DATE), m.Minutes
;
```

I cannot, of course, test this as no test data or table definitions were provided.